# Eloquent relationship two parent and child

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables: 1. questionbank 2. questiontype 3. questions

I need to retrieve the json response :

```
[{"questiontitle":"OSCE","questionbank":"osce bank","questiontype":"osce type"}]
```

My Models are:

1. questionbank

   class Questionbank extends Model {

   ```
   protected $fillable = [];

   protected $table = "QuestionBank";

   protected $dates = [];
   protected $primaryKey = "QuestionBankID";

   protected $visible = ["QuestionBank"];

   public static $rules = [
       // Validation rules
   ];
   ```

   }
2. questiontype

   class questiontype extends Model {

   ```
   protected $fillable = [];

   protected $dates = [];

   protected $table = "QuestionType";

   protected $primarykey = "QuestionTypeID";

   protected $visible = ["QuestionType"];

   public static $rules = [
       // Validation rules
   ];

   // Relationships
   ```

   }
3. questions

   class Questions extends Model {

   ```
   protected $fillable = ["QuestionTitle"];

   protected $dates = [];

   protected $primaryKey = "QuestionID";
   protected $foreignKey = "QuestionBankID";

   public static $rules = [
       // Validation rules
   ];
   protected $visible = ["QuestionTitle","QuestionBank","QuestionType"];
   // Relationships
   ```

   public function QuestionBank() {
           return $this->hasManyThrough('App\QuestionBank', 'App\questiontype', 'QuestionBankID', 'QuestionTypeID', 'QuestionBankID', 'QuestionTypeID');
       }
   }

i got the error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'QuestionType.QuestionBankID' in 'field list' (SQL: select `QuestionBank`.*, `QuestionType`.`QuestionBankID` from `QuestionBank` inner join `QuestionType` on `QuestionType`.`QuestionTypeID` = `QuestionBank`.`QuestionTypeID` where `QuestionType`.`QuestionBankID`
```

Comment: does the questions have single bank and type or is it a hasmany

Comment: Can you elaborate the relations .. it's not clear